# unable to load dll library with "run jetty run"

Tags: eclipse, dll, jetty, native

In my project i try to load a native DLL with

System.loadLibrary().

This works fine with wtp jetty extension and maven jetty plugin. But with the run jetty run eclipse plugin, the Server hangs up without error message. Is this a limitation or can this be configured?

Comment: There is no error message. The thread does Not respond anymore. The solution for The project is to run jetty as Main class inside the project; But it would be fine to use the plugin.